# Secondary IP on NIC, not recognized by network

Tags: routing, local-area-network, windows-sbs-2011

I have a server with SBS 2011 standard, on which because of provider difficulties because they limit port forwarding options via ipv4, I need to add a secondary IP address.

I added the second IP under advanced network options

[image]

Now trouble i'm having is having this second IP address accessible/findable to the network so the internet router can forward the ports to it.

The SBS 2011 server is also the DHCP server and DNS server.

If I try to ping the secondary I get timed out, if I ping the primary it's an immediate hit.

Changing the primary ip is impossible, it would break the company. This is only intended for temporary, in 3 weeks we get a new internet connection that should work properly, but I need this working in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently it can't be done, the subnet mask of sbs 2011 only supports 'class C' subnets according to Merv

> SBS 2008 – How to Change the Server’s IP Address
>   http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/03/sbs-2008-how-to-change-servers-ip.html
>   **And note that SBS 2011, like SBS 2008, only supports a Class C subnet.**
>   How the Connect to the Internet Wizard works
>   http://sbs.seandaniel.com/2008/09/how-connect-to-internet-wizard-works.html
>
> Merv  Porter

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2aabd5f-ca5d-4ebe-9ff3-8c38823cfc5a/how-can-i-change-the-subnet-and-gateway-for-the-dhcp-server-on-sbs-2011?forum=smallbusinessserver#f9533ee7-82c7-4ec1-aec2-43f1cc23874f

Answer (score 1):

Your IP address `192.168.178.222` is not in the same subnet `192.168.0.0/24` as all the other devices. Use an IP address within the subnet and outside your DHCP scope, e.g. `192.168.0.223`.

It seems you are not familiar with networks. The `/24` ([*Classless Inter-Domain Routing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)) CIDR notation equals your subnet mask `255.255.255.0`; the range being `192.168.0.0` - `192.168.0.255`.

If the secondary IP **must** be on `192.168.178.0/24`, you have a flaw in your testing. You need to manually add a device to the same subnet and ping within that network, because you don't have routing from your LAN to that new network.

Comment: I can't. Because the router that we have to use the next 3 week doesn't support port forwarding to *anything* outside 192.168.178.*  but the internal network needs to function in the 192.168.0.* range because otherwise the entire business doesn't function.

Comment: Okay, but I **can't** change the ip range 192.168.178.*. The router only allow portforwarding to that range. these are the unfortunate options I have. which is much less than ideal, granted. Is there someway I can fiddle with the settings, changing subnets whatever on server to make it work without bring the office crashing down?

Answer (score 0):

Go buy a new router. I assume you are using the equivalent of a Netgear or DLink?  Not expensive in such cases and worth the bottle of aspirin it will replace.